# Incluir arquivos e ficar com varias repetições das tags <html> e <body> pode dar problema?

Tags: php, html, html5

Supondo que eu tenho um arquivo chamado `home.php` e ele é tem os seguintes códigos:

```
<html>
<head>
    <p>Head do home.php</p>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Body do home.php</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Ai eu também tenho o arquivo `menu.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <p>Head do menu.php</p>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Body do menu.php</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

E também tenho por exemplo, um arquivo para incluir os arquivos pelo `header`, o `ìncludes.php` por exemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

E ai a estrutura dos arquivos(`home.php`, `contato.php`, `pedidos.php` e por ai vai...) ficariam assim:

```
<?php
include_once 'includes.php';
include_once 'menu.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <p>Head do home.php/contato.php e por ai vai...</p>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Body do home.php/contato.php e por ai vai...</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Tudo funciona corretamente, porém, se formos inspecionar o codigo fonta da pagina, vemos do seguinte jeito (com varias repetições das tags `<html>` e `<body>`, isso pode dar problema ou os navegadores corrigem?):

```
 <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html><html>
<head>
    <p>Head do menu.php</p>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Body do menu.php</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html><html>
<head>
    <p>Head do home.php/contato.php e por ai vai...</p>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Body do home.php/contato.php e por ai vai...</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionar funciona (talvez não no IE), mas funcionar nem sempre é correto ou a melhor forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navegadores mais modernos e pré-modernos (IE 8+) até corrigem, mas isso é uma prática ruim e desaconselhável. Um *include* deve conter apenas o código que interessa naquele trecho da página, e não uma estrutura completa de página, com `<html>`, `<head>` e `<body>`.

Além de poder causar algum prejuízo na performance da página, pois o navegador terá mais código para carregar e fazer a correção, não vejo muito sentido desenvolver uma página desta forma.

O ideal é que a *include* contenha apenas o código que você quer inserir na página, como, por exemplo, a página `index.php`:

```
<html>
<?php
include_once 'head.php';

     // o head.php teria o código do <head></head>
     // com as meta-tags, scripts e o que for
     // necessário incluir neste bloco

?>
<body>
<?php
include_once 'menu.php';

     // o menu.php teria o HTML do menu, ex.:
     // <nav> conteúdo do menu </nav>
?>

....
CONTEÚDO DA HOME
....

<?php
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```